# Create new row with data from another row/column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working with an old database with lots of data.  I don't have much access, but I can do queries.

My query is:

```
SELECT id, driver, event_name, score, season_grade
FROM driver d
INNER JOIN events e ON d.driverId = e.driverId
INNER JOIN eventscore es ON e.eventId = es.eventId
INNER JOIN seasonsummary ss ON d.driverId = ss.driverId
```

I have a SQL SELECT result set that looks like this:

```
id     driver     event_name    score   season_grade          
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Smith      California    23      A
1      Smith      London        11      A
1      Smith      Boise         76      A
2      Satoru     Paris         5       C
2      Satoru     Dubai         6       C
2      Satoru     Havana        14      C
3      Qura       Tokyo         21      B
3      Qura       Miami         45      B
3      Qura       Sidney        18      B
```

As you can kindly see, the `season_grade` is **duplicated** for each driver.

I would like to remove the `season_grade` column, and add it as a row for each driver, like this:

```
id     driver     event_name      score             
--------------------------------------
1      Smith      California      23     
1      Smith      London          11     
1      Smith      Boise           76  
1      Smith      Season Score    A   
2      Satoru     Paris           5      
2      Satoru     Dubai           6      
2      Satoru     Havana          14
2      Satoru     Season Score    C
3      Qura       Tokyo           21     
3      Qura       Miami           45     
3      Qura       Sidney          18
3      Qura       Season Score    B
```

Would this be possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do that,  Score is an integer value.  You shouldn't mix data types.  Season grade should have been stored in a separate table.  Now, if you want to REPORT it that way, that's just fine, but you'd do that in code, not in an SQL query.

Comment: @TimRoberts Why can't I do it in SQL Server?  It's just for a report.  Do you mean do it in Python or something like that?

Comment: What you are asking for is antithetical to the relational set theory underpinning all databases. You can build reports this way in SQL, but it's better to do it in the reporting tool, **after** returning the data from the database the way you already have it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't have a reporting tool, just SQL Server studio to do my `SELECT` queries in.

Comment: You have something you're using to view the data. Let that tool worry about this conversion. If you're the only one to ever look at this, then you should just leave it alone.

Comment: Right.  If you're submitting this to a customer or a manager, you're surely not just printing out an SQLServer query and calling it good.

Comment: @TimRoberts true I am copy & pasting it to an Excel spreadsheet but I don't know enough about Excel to have it do any data transformations

Comment: Also, I just noticed the "2012" tag. SQL Server 2012 has been formally end-of-life for a few years now. This means it hasn't had any updates -- **not even critical security patches** -- for a long time now. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it. Updated to a supported version is job #1 here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn ok thanks but I don't have control over the server stuff.  I just need to pull data from it.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell You have influence over someone who does.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am sorry I unfortunately don't, the server is located in a datacenter in California.  I just have to do a few reports because they are going to do something to all this data soon and they want me to finish them.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really bad practice as you are kinda mixing column meanings, but if you REALLY wanted to do it

```
SELECT id, driver, event_name, score
FROM (
    SELECT id, driver, event_name, CAST(score AS varchar(20)) AS score, 1 AS order_rank
    FROM driver AS d
    INNER JOIN events e ON d.driverId = e.driverId
    INNER JOIN eventscore es ON e.eventId = es.eventId
    INNER JOIN seasonsummary ss ON d.driverId = ss.driverId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT id, driver, "season_score", season_grade, 2 AS order_rank
    FROM driver AS d
    INNER JOIN events e ON d.driverId = e.driverId
    INNER JOIN eventscore es ON e.eventId = es.eventId
    INNER JOIN seasonsummary ss ON d.driverId = ss.driverId
) AS data
ORDER BY driver, order_rank
```

Basically you create  distinct view of driver/grades and then union it to the first query with an ordering column, this will ensure it is always at the bottom of the list, then use it as a subquery and order by driver and ranking column.

Comment: He told you that.  He does two different queries, one for score and one for grade, and then mixes them.  It has to convert the score to a string for it to work.  This works, but it is tacky.  ;)

Comment: so you remove the score from the first query, then create a second query with distinct driver/score combinations, then union them together, but that alone will not work because you have  
3      Qura       Sidney          18
3      Qura       Season Score 
this means if you order by event_name it will do this 
3      Qura   Season Score B
3      Qura   Sidney    18
so to compensate for that and to get the score always as the last entry, we add a static "ranking" column to each leg of our union, then when we order, we just have to always have the last order clause as the rank.

Comment: @TimRoberts I agree :)

Comment: @BrianK.Burge thank you, I know it's not great, but I just need to get this out quick.  I appreciate your answer and will mark it as solved by you when this stack overflow lets me.  thank u

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `UNION ALL` embedded in a `CROSS APPLY` to achieve your result. This combines the results of the two independent join branches. Since you have mixed data types, you need to apply a conversion.

If you wish to place the `season_grade` values after the other scores, you can add a fixed `sortOrder` value to each UNION branch and reference that in the `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT d.id, d.driver, u.event_name, u.score
FROM driver d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT e.event_name, CAST(es.score AS VARCHAR(100)) AS score, 1 as sortOrder
    FROM events e
    INNER JOIN eventscore es ON e.eventId = es.eventId
    WHERE e.driverId = d.driverId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Season Score' AS event_name, ss.season_grade AS score, 2 as sortOrder
    FROM seasonsummary ss
    WHERE ss.driverId = d.driverId
) u
ORDER BY d.id, u.sortOrder
```

Note that if either the event or seasonsummary portion of the query yields zero results, the other results will still be included. The inner joins of your original query would have required both to be present to produce any results.

Results:

| id | driver | event_name | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith | California | 23 |
| 1 | Smith | London | 11 |
| 1 | Smith | Boise | 76 |
| 1 | Smith | Season Score | A |
| 2 | Satoru | Paris | 5 |
| 2 | Satoru | Dubai | 6 |
| 2 | Satoru | Havana | 14 |
| 2 | Satoru | Season Score | C |
| 3 | Qura | Tokyo | 21 |
| 3 | Qura | Miami | 45 |
| 3 | Qura | Sidney | 18 |
| 3 | Qura | Season Score | B |

See [this db<> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J0wogoeK) for a demo.

Comment: Does the CROSS APPLY do the conversion?

Comment: No. The conversion needs to be applied before the UNION.  The first part uses `CAST` to convert `INT` to `VARCHAR`. The second part already yields a `VARCHAR` column type.